# BizTalk xpath with a default namespace and no prefixes

Tags: xpath, biztalk

I'm struggling with the BizTalk xpath functionality 

 
- the message I'm getting has a blank default namespace

 
- in C# I'd add a NameSpaceManager

- but I can't see how I can do this in a BizTalk Expression ?

All I'm failing to do is get the values of the HasErrors and NumberOfErrors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImportIndexDocumentResponse   
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"        
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://www.aniteps.com/xml/schemas/awm/images4">
  <HasErrors>false</HasErrors>
  <NumberOfErrors xsi:type="xsd:int">0</NumberOfErrors>
  <ErrorDescription xsi:type="xsd:string">No exception ocurred.</ErrorDescription>
  ...
```

Comment: The title of the question is misleading. The default namespace is *not* blank. It is "http://www.aniteps.com/xml/schemas/awm/images4". What you mean is "with no namespace prefix".

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Dimitre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer using `local-name()` is wrong as it allows unwanted elements to be selected, such as:

- OhMy:HasErrors
- Different:HasErrors
- UnWanted:HasErrors

---

Here is one correct solution:

**In case it is not possible to bind a prefix to the default namespace** "http://www.aniteps.com/xml/schemas/awm/images4", **one can use the standard XPath function [`namespace-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-namespace)** to specify that the element must reside in a given namespace.

**Thereforere, one example of XPath expressions that select the wanted two kind of nodes is**:

```
/*/*[namespace-uri() = 'http://www.aniteps.com/xml/schemas/awm/images4'
   and
     name() = 'HasErrors'
    ]
```

and the expression:

```
/*/*[namespace-uri() = 'http://www.aniteps.com/xml/schemas/awm/images4'
   and
     name() = 'NumberOfErrors'
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are not repeating you could promote them from the response schema as distinguished fields. Then you do not have to worry about coding. Just use:

```
x = YourMessageName.HasErrors;
```

If it is a web/wcf reference, you can promote values from the reference.xsd (or xyz.xsd with "Consume Wcf Service Wizard"). Just be aware of that if you update the reference they will "disappear".

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Reference.xsd generated for the web service I'm using ... I believe this is because it's only returning simple types, in this case a string